# My 2 months released app won't show up with using non-english text on Google Play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

It's been around two months since I released my app on Google play with multi versions been uploaded.
I use two main languages English and Arabic, and I did provide the main store listing in two languages and I did make the Arabic translation. Moreover, I did include the keywords I want, and the app should show up while searching within the app title, short and long description.
With the English name of the app, I can find it the first one, but if I used any similar word or the Arabic name of the app it won't show up.
Also, I did follow Google recommendations relating to different parts of the app listing, and translations and my app is live, and is no violations on it.

So what is exactly I am missing? how can I make my app show up with specific words on search? is there missing data I should add in the app, although I the app does contain the application details in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file including name, icon, label, etc but all those are in English if that has anything to do with it.

If there is any missing information needed to help answer the question I am ready to provide

Comment: this seems to be an issue using Google play console and not a programming issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after waiting the version to be released, synced, and a lot of research, I was able to fix it, and yes you have to add some details in the `AndroidManifest.xml` not just enhance the store listing, and this is what I was looking for but I could find it easily in doc, hope this helps someone else:

You can add title, description and keywords for the app with different languages, as following:

In `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `application` tag:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="title"
        android:resource="@array/title_array" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="description"
        android:resource="@array/description_array" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.android.metadata.keywords"
        android:resource="@array/keywords_en" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.android.metadata.keywords.ar"
        android:resource="@array/keywords_ar" />
```

In `String.xml` add those strings:

```
<string-array name="title_array">
    <item>AppName</item>
    <item>اسم التطبيق</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="description_array">
    <item>This is a description of the app</item>
    <item>هذا وصف للتطبيق</item>
</string-array>
<array name="keywords_en">
    <item>App</item>
    <item>test</item>
    <item>tst</item>
</array>
<array name="keywords_ar">
    <item>تطبيق</item>
    <item>ططبيق</item>
</array>
```

And this help me to make my app show up different language google play listing. Notice I did also added different keywords I want on store listing